# Using perl regex constructs in VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net, regex, perl, translation

In perl you can write

```
$string =~ tr/[a,e,i,o,u,y]/[A,E,I,O,U,Y]/;
```

for example.

Is it possible to achieve the same "translation" effects with VB.Net regexes?

Thanks you!

PS: I'm not searching for a way to port this very example, it's more of a curiosity question :)

Comment: The example is more concisely written as `$string =~ tr/aeiouy/AEIOUY/;`

Comment: The surprising thing is that it works correctly as he wrote it, since the brackets and commas are in the same place in both strings.  It just replaces brackets and commas with the same character.  That does throw off the replacement count, but that's frequently unused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard method for this. You can do it by iterating over each character in your input string and using a dictionary to map it to another character (or leave it unchanged if the character is not found in the dictionary). The result can be built using a `StringBuilder` for performance reasons.

If performance is not an issue then you might be able to use a few replace operations instead:

```
s = s.Replace("a", "A")
     .Replace("e", "E")
     ...
     .Replace("y", "Y");
```

Comment: As I said, I'm not trying to replicate the behaviour of this very example, but I just wanted to now if there was a similar construct :)

Comment: @CFP: Then the answer is no, but you can write one yourself using the method I described in my answer (first paragraph).

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do this:

```
public string fakeTR(string theString, char[] org, char[] rep)
{
  for(int i=0;i<org.lenght;i++)
  {
    theString = theString.Replace(org[i], rep[i]);
  }
  return theString;
}

You would be able to call it with somewhat clunky but shorter:

string v = "Black in South Dakota";
v = fakeTR(v, new char[]{'B','l','a','c','k'}, new char[]{'W','h','i','t','e'});
```

H/T http://discuss.joelonsoftware.com/default.asp?dotnet.12.306220.6